# PHP File Transfer Script .. ALMOST DONE!

Tags: php, ftp, transfer

Can someone figure out what this is not working?  I kept trying different things, double checking syntax etc but I get the error message I have setup for when a file does not transfer.  This is my first PHP script.

I appreciate any help I will do research in the meantime.

Using NetBeans

```
<?php
$user = "username";
$password = "password";
$server_file = 'mag_hounddog.mp3';
$local_file = 'C:\users\kazuiman\desktop\mag_hounddog.mp3';

$ftp_server = "ftp.mysite.com";

// setup a basic connection to the ftp server
$connectionID = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Connection was Not Successful");

// login with username and password for your account
$loginResult = ftp_login($connectionID, $user, $password);

echo ftp_pwd($connectionID);

// changes the directory to the tvstation you can hard code one in here.

if (ftp_chdir($connectionID, "test1nbiiwcdp_apps/tv2beta/streams/_definst_/")) {
    echo "Current Directory is Now..." . ftp_pwd($connectionID) . "\n";
} else {
    echo "Error Changing Directory .. perhaps it doesn't exist?";
}

// Now to download the files and put them onto your local machine
if (ftp_get($connectionID, $local_file, $remote_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Succesfully written $server_file to $local_file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem with the FTP transfer please check script\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($connectionID)

?>
```

Comment: Which error is it actually? *"There was a problem..."*?

Comment: Every developer should be able to debug his own code. That is what developers do every day.

Comment: @Christian Sciberras: ftp_get does not give the specific error, it just returns TRUE on success and FALSE on failure.

Comment: @Mads.Ohm: He didn't specify which function actually faulted. You seem to assume `ftp_get()`?

Comment: @Christian: Ahh, sorry. I assumed the error at `ftp_get()` because Matthew did write "[...] when a file does not transfer"

Answer (score 1):

You have never defined the variable `$remote_file`.

In your preamble it is called `$server_file`.

Is this a copy-paste-error?